# Salvage droid mission keeps giving "already opened this cargo"

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've been sending damage droids to kashyyyk in the second slot a bunch, after luckily unlocking Chiss HSP on bronze.

Now other than the usual VIP and credit rewards, sometimes I'm given the message that I've already opened this cargo and to please have these bux. It started out at 2 and it's up to 12 now, increment of 2 each time.

Has anybody else seen this yet? Maybe it's because I've unlocked a level already? I don't know if you can get other levels from different areas.

Answer (score 1):

I also get a bux reward when opening a cargo container for cargo that I've already received.  I have not noticed your pattern of increasing bux rewards - my rewards have varied from 2 - 10 bux; but it could be that since I have several bitizens and 2 levels unlocked that the reward varies depending on what you see again?

One pattern I can confirm: When I unlock a bitizen, I first get the typical find bitizen quest to grant them access - this will give you 1 buck back; and then I will immediately get a new cargo delivery that gives me a 5 bux reward for having already received this cargo.  This means that you get a refund of 6 bux on the off-chance that you actually manage to unlock a new bitizen.